# Scan QR Code open Link p

Tags: javascript, redirect, qr-code, scanning

Instead of opening an alert in the following **Javascript** code I want to redirect to a URL where the URL is imported from a **QR-Code** scan but sadly am no good with **Javascript**. Any help?

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
function scanCode(){
        cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
          function (result) {
              setTimeout(function() {alert('Very good. ' + result.text);}, 500);
          }, 
          function (error) {alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
          }
       );
    }
</script>
```

Comment: instead of alert(), have `window.location=result.text`?

Comment: A friendly tip: The answer to your question could be found be found very easily by googling "javascript redirect to url" or something along those lines.  It's best to look for the answer yourself before posting to SO

Answer (score 0):

Version with a redirection as an HTTP redirect :

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
function scanCode(){
        cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
          function (result) {
              setTimeout(function() {windows.location.replace(result.text);}, 500);
          }, 
          function (error) {alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
          }
       );
    }
</script>
```

Version with a redirection as clicking on a link :

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
function scanCode(){
        cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
          function (result) {
              setTimeout(function() {windows.location.href(result.text);}, 500);
          }, 
          function (error) {alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
          }
       );
    }
</script>
```